# why .times is being difficult - Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

Can someone please explain to me why the Ruby function .times is being difficult

```
str.chars.map{|letter| num.times{letter.next}}
```

is producing just the number (`num`) for however many letters were in the word instead of moving each letter down the alphabet (`.next`) that many times. I know it seems simple but from what i understand of `.times` this is the way to use it but something like this has happened `many.times`....that was a joke.

Answer (score 1):

`num.times` returns the value of `num`.  You should use something like below:

```
str.chars.map{|letter| num.times{ letter = letter.next }; letter }
```

Comment: `('letter'.ord + num).chr`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'd do something like

```
def caesar_up(string, n)
  string.chars.map { |char| (char.ord + n).chr }.join
end
```

Then use it like `caesar_up("MOM", 2)` to get `"OQO"`

Comment: From mudasobwa's comment

Answer (score 0):

```
> 'abc'.chars.map{|c| c.tap { 3.times{c.next!} } }.join
=> "def"
```

or perhaps

```
3.times.inject(letter){|a,_| a.next}
```

but neither is very readable.